# PHP - Mysqli monthly attendance calendar

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my attendance table.

```
id   employee_name   attStatus      empdates
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1    Arun               p             2020-03-15 09:30:28.120
2    Alex               a             2020-03-16 09:30:28.120
3    Jimy               p             2020-03-17 09:30:28.120

---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want the result like the following way

[image]

how can i write the mysqli script to print monthly attendance of every employee?

Comment: Please, don't simply ask the community to solve the entire problem for you. You're expected to make an effort. There are tutorials and other questions about the same problem out there, that should get you started.

Comment: Hi, this seems a nice exercise to learn some aspects of PHP date/SQL management, I advice you to do it by yourself.

Comment: @El_Vanja - I didn't say you have to write full code for me. I need some idea/logic to get the desired output. Yes, I found some tutorials from StackOverflow somewhat similar to the above query. but some of them are SQL queries.

Comment: @ankabot - Thanks for the feedback, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this. Code is bit lengthy.

```
$first_day_this_month = date('Y-m-01'); 
$last_day_this_month  = date('Y-m-t');

$sql = "SELECT eid,
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 1, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '01', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 2, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '02', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 3, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '03', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 4, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '04', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 5, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '05', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 6, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '06', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 7, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '07', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 8, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '08', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 9, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '09', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 10, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '10',
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 11, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '11', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 12, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '12', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 13, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '13', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 14, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '14', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 15, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '15', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 16, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '16', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 17, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '17', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 18, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '18', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 19, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '19', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 20, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '20', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 21, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '21', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 22, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '22', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 23, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '23', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 24, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '24', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 25, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '25', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 26, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '26', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 27, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '27', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 28, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '28', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 29, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '29', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 30, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '30',  
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(DAY(`empdates`) = 31, `attStatus`, NULL)) AS '31', 
  COUNT(if(`attStatus`='P', `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'totalP',
  COUNT(if(`attStatus`='A', `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'totalA',
  COUNT(if(`attStatus`='L', `attStatus`, NULL)) AS 'totalL'

FROM `attendance `
WHERE `empdates` BETWEEN '".$first_day_this_month."' AND '".$last_day_this_month."' 
GROUP BY id";
```